# Process Start And Show C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using C# (WPF)
I have full path of process and i start the process with with `Process.Start()` command.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.shartInfo.FileName = fullPathOfFile;
p.Start();
```

Now, i want to show process that i'm start before (after `Start()` command).

i.e if i start the notepad and the user minimize the notepad and click on `Start Notepad` in my application i want to check if i running notepad before, if so then show the running notepad to user.

```
if p is running:
   Show p
else
   Start p
```

how can i do it in C#?
Thanks.

Comment: To simplify: a) check if a process is running already and bring its main window to the front and b) if it is not running, start it. Is that correct? Do you own the code of the target process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if process with following name is already running you can use `Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)` method.

In case process is running you can maximize it's window by using `Pinvoke`. Call `ShowWindow` with `SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED` Parameter.

Otherwise you can simply call `Process.Start(processName)` to start a process.
Try following

```
internal class MyClass
{
  //use this flag to maximize process window.
  const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
  //use this flag to open process window normally.
  const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var processName = "notepad";
    var process = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName).FirstOrDefault();
    if (process != null)
      ShowWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    else
      Process.Start(processName);
  }
}
```

Comment: I can show the application without Maximized the window? just to show

Comment: @MikeBrown Yes you can, Just pass `1` as a second parameter to `ShowWindow` function. `1` Corresponds to `SW_SHOWNORMAL` flag.

Comment: @MikeBrown Glad if helped.

Answer (score 1):

After the p.Start() call, p.Id gives you the process id.
Later you can use Process.GetProcessById( id ) to find the running process.

To bring its window to front is a bit more complicated task.
See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2976/Detect-if-another-process-is-running-and-bring-it